# Embedding sounds in as3/flash without any loss of quality?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I've looked everywhere online for a solution to this problem with no avail.  I've also check this site's extensive Q+A listing for some kind of solution, but still nothing.  I've decided, with much hesitation, to pose the question my self, so here we go.

I'm creating an as3/flash game, and am currently working with sounds loaded via URL Requests:

```
public var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
```

then in the init():

```
mySound.load(new URLRequest("pathToFile/soundFileName.mp3"));
```

then of course, playing the sound:

```
mySound.play();
```

Now, of course doing it like this, they do not embed in the SWF upon export.  I've tried bringing the sounds into the library and giving them as3 linkage and class names, and yes this worked, but it degraded the quality of the sounds IMMENSELY!  How do I get around the degradation of the sound quality.

I've seen similar questions, but none seem to talk about the complete loss of quality when importing them into the library and using the as3 linkage/class method, so that brought me here.

I'm posing the question to the community of Stack Overflow, please help, any advice at all would be much appreciated.

To be clear, my question is: How do I embed the sounds into the SWF upon export and avoid any loss of sound quality?

Comment: There is a setting in FLash CS that controls sound quality, I remember seeing that. Check sound properties in the library and publishing settings of your project for them.

Comment: Yep, that's all it was.  Jeez, and I thought I checked everything, but apparently not.  Thanks, Vesper.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in FLash CS that controls sound quality, I remember seeing that. Check sound properties in the library and publishing settings of your project for them. –  Vesper

Comment: I just copy and pasted the comment from Vesper, so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

SoundTransform class can be used by...

```
var volumeAdjust:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
volumeAdjust.volume = .6;
volumeAdjust.pan = 0;
```

you can check other properties of this class, If you are more interested you can go for Microphone and MicEnhanceOption.